# Move from 2003 to 2008 Microsoft Clustering Technologies

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, cluster

I'm currently supporting a Windows 2003 R2 system that's using Microsoft Cluster Service and Virtual Server 2005 R2 SP1.

My organization is planning on moving to Windows Server 2008 and I would like to know the experiences you've had doing that transition.

What were the main issues you've had?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running an all-windows infrastructure to begin with, there shouldn't really be any issues.  We had problems in our transition because our DNS is not Microsoft based and doesn't support Dynamic DNS updates.  The 2008 clustering wizards **really** try to help you out by making sure all the DNS stuff is functioning properly, but they just weren't designed for an environment without DDNS.  There are workarounds to get it working, but it's kind of a headache.

We actually have an open support case with Microsoft regarding this issue.  They claim the fix will be implemented in 2008 R2 (aka Win7 Server).

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could go into enormous detail on the subject but the truth is that it went incredibly smoothly with literally no issues whatsoever. Sorry to be boring.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'm happy that all went well. It should always be like that.
There's nothing wrong about being boring ;-)
It happens a lot to me to.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest change will come from your SAN.  Your Shared Storage needs to support SCSI-3 Persistant Reservations.

This required quite a bit of support from EMC getting our arrays upgraded with a later firmware.